# Wordpress - Meta query with post id

Tags: php, wordpress

Can I add `ID` to the `$args` array? I need to check if the key value pair custom field exists for a particular post. Now it checks if the key value pair exists in any post. Or do I need to perform the query and then check for my value in the returned array?

```
    $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'ID' => $_POST['post_id'],
     'meta_query' => array(
             array(
                     'key' => 'claim',
                     'value' => $user_ID
             )
     )
    );

    // perform the query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $vid_ids = $query->posts;

    if ( empty( $vid_ids ) ) {
         add_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'claim', $user_ID );
    }else{
        echo "sorry";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please reference the Codex entry for [post/page parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters)  for WP_Query().
You can pass single post id with this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => 7 ) );
```

If you want to pass multiple post id's use

```
 $myarray = array('100', '222');

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'post__in'      => $myarray
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: So what if I have only one post id and need the args as well. Can I do `$query = new WP_Query( array( 'p' => 7, $args ) );` ? seems to work. Tried it.

Comment: This syntax is wrong. You can use p just like you pass other params. In your case replace ID with p.

Comment: That seems to do it.

Comment: You can set every variable in the $args array and just pass it to WP_Query. No need to complicate simple things.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_post_meta` to get custom field value for your object.

```
$claims=get_post_meta($ID,'claim');
$exists=false;    
if(count($claims)>0)
{
    foreach($claims as $claim)   
    {
        if($claim==$user_ID)
        {
            $exists=true;
            break;
        }
    } 
}
if(!$exists)
{
    add_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'claim', $user_ID );
}
```

Comment: Can I use `get_post_meta` to check the key and value? I have multiple `claim `custom fields with user ids as values.

Comment: @ciprian I've updated my answer. This should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you. Now considering the other answer ... if I change 'ID' to 'p' it works as well. Just finished testing it. Which one of these methods is faster?

Comment: This one should be faster since it uses meta cache. For example, you loaded page with 30 posts, at the same time all meta for these posts was retrieved as well. So no matter how many times you call get_post_meta for any of these 30 posts, no more db queries will be done. With WP_Query you'll be doing db query for every check.